# Reading in multiple files in directory using python

Tags: python

I'm trying to open each file from a directory and print the contents, so I have a code as such:

```
import os, sys

def printFiles(dir):
    os.chdir(dir)
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        myFile = open(f,'r')
        lines = myFile.read()
        print lines
        myFile.close()

printFiles(sys.argv[1])
```

The program runs, but the problem here is that it is only printing one of the contents of the file, probably the last file that it has read. Does this have something to do with the open() function?

Edit: added last line that takes in sys.argv. That's the whole code, and it still only prints the last file.

Comment: Are you sure? What happens if you just print `f` within your loop - how many filenames is it showing it's looping over?

Comment: @JonClements when I `print f` it does print all the file names in the directory.

Comment: @maregor Are some files empty for instance?

Comment: @JonClements no, they all have contents. It still prints the last file of any directory only.

Comment: Why do you call `os.chdir()`?

Comment: @Tagc without it, it would produce `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'`

Comment: What argument were you passing as `dir` to `printFiles()`?

Comment: Okay, so what argument are passing on the command-line? What's the literal value of `sys.argv[1]` during your tests?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120833/discussion-between-tagc-and-maregor).

Comment: `python printFiles.py /Users/myusername/Desktop/testdir`

Comment: @maregor check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/352198/reading-all-files-from-a-directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with directory and file paths.

Option 1 - chdir:

```
def printFiles(dir):
    os.chdir(dir)
    for f in os.listdir('.'):
        myFile = open(f,'r')
        # ...
```

Option 2 - computing full path:

```
def printFiles(dir):
    # no chdir here
    for f in os.listdir(dir):
        myFile = open(os.path.join(dir, f), 'r')
        # ...
```

But you are combining both options - that's wrong.

This is why I prefer [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use) - it's much simpler:

```
from pathlib import Path

def printFiles(dir):
    dir = Path(dir)
    for f in dir.iterdir():
        myFile = f.open()
        # ...
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty getting the first and second options to work. They still result in printing the last file only... I prefer if I didn't have to import but I would use it if no other options are available.

Comment: @maregor: it works for me... https://gist.github.com/messa/a257e5dd3522b5cae883ea886f6dc64a#file-example-txt

Comment: So it does... I tried editing my code to have the same exact lines as yours and it doesn't work, but when I copy paste your code into mines it does. It completely bewilders me.

Comment: @maregor: Are you mixing tabs and spaces? :) If that `print` line ends up on the same level as the `for` (instead of being in the `for` block) it would have the exact same results as you are reporting.

Comment: Thanks. I think that was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself certainly should print the contents of every file.
However, if you supply a local path and not a global path it will not work.

For example, imagine you have the following folder structure:

```
./a
./a/x.txt
./a/y.txt
./a/a
./a/a/x.txt
```

If you now run

```
printFiles('a')
```

you will only get the contents of *x.txt*, because *os.listdir* will be executed from within *a*, and will list the contents of the internal *a/a* folder, which only has *x.txt*.

Comment: I did supply the full path, and I had only 3 files in it, but it would just print out the last file in any directory that I put into it.